# Change color of visited links in Chrome 33

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Since Google distributed Chrome in version 33, it is not possible anymore to use the `custom.css` file to set the color of visited links. Is there another possibility for Chrome 33?

Comment: http://chromespot.com/forum/google-chrome-troubleshooting/26429-chrome-33-update-what-happened-to-my-visited-links.html Solution on the buttom that works!

Comment: Wait a second, Chrome doesn’t have a built-in way to select the color of links like every single other browser has had since the beginning of time‽ Why exactly did I ever think Chrome was so great?

Answer (score 19):

Here's a solution that works for all platform and versions of Chrome.

1. Install the [Stylus extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne).
2. Right-click the Stylus browser action icon (looks like the letter S in a box) and select "Open styles manager".
3. Click "Write new style".
4. Copy & paste the following into the large text area on the right hand side:

   ```
   a:visited { color: red ! important }
   ```
5. Enter a name for the style (on the left hand side, near the top).
6. Click the "Save" button (right below the name).
7. Find a page with visited link, refresh, and you'll see the new color.
   You can find colors you like [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colors.asp), and use code like `rgb(255, 0, 0)` in place of `red`

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sVkgKCIxyaM)

Comment: Correction -- step 2 s/b Click "More Tools"

Comment: @user215779 that's right, thank you! Fixed

Comment: worked for me as well

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me... I look at Wikipedia and the visited links stay the same colors.

Comment: The Stylist extension seems to have been removed from the store unfortunately

Comment: I've updated the instructions to reference a similar extension (Stylus).

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. Should've done this a long time back instead of struggling with shades of blue.

Answer (score 3):

You should create a chrome extension. It's not a big deal but more cumbersome than before.

To guide you, create a `content script` extension, use the `inject css` ability and set the `permissions` to any site(`*://*/*`)

For further details have a look here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: If you’re going to be foolish enough to keep using Chrome and jump through hoops to do what used to be trivial, then you may as well just use an existing user-stylehseet extension and just use your current stylesheet instead of making a whole new extension.

Comment: No way I'm going to write my own extension to get this small thing done. Are we going backwards with respect to automating daily chores, this should be part of chrome for sure. **sigh**

Answer (score 3):

The Stylist extension doesn't appear in Chrome webstore anymore.  An alternative is the [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) extension.  If the link doesn't work just go to google chrome webstore and do a search for Stylebot.  It's very easy to use and you can change more than just link colors to any site including google.  Install the extension, go to Chrome > More tools > extensions > Stylebot > options > styles > Add New Style.  Then add a url and some css styling.  Here's my css style I use for google.com:

[image]

the result looks like this for a google search:

[image]

It's very easy to see now the links I've already visited.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use UserScript (like Tampermonkey) instead of Stylus extension, use this UserScript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Match Every Site
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.1
// @description  change a visited link
// @author       You
// @match        *://*/*

// for change CSS
// @grant    GM_addStyle

// ==/UserScript==


GM_addStyle ( `
  a:link { color: #0f00fb9e ! important }  // if you also want to change the color of unvisited links
  a:visited { color: red ! important }
` );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two extensions for just that:

[**Link Text Color**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-text-color/djajcdbelhandnaichcbohaoefndhnde)

[**Visited**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/visited/bfcodeehkjogenemacopdbhabjebnbah)

I have tested both and both work.
Link Text Color has more options but if you just want to mark visited links Visited do just that perfect.

Comment: Might be helpful to provide some backround of what you know about the links provided.  Even a "I haven't tried these but they look helpful" is more helpful than nothing.